# .htaccess seems to be required but I can not find it

Tags: htaccess

I installed WordPress on Ubuntu 22.04 and when I tried to write a post or edit the default post that comes pre-installed I got an error message:

> The response is not a valid JSON response

After a lot of googling and also seeing there was no *.htaccess* file in the root directory, I thought that the reason for this was that in the apache configuration file I had `AllowOverride None`. I made a directory specific (to the root directory of my WordPress installation) `AllowOverride All` and restarted apache. Now I can edit and make new posts without the error message.

I assumed that when I looked at the contents of the root directory I would see a *.htaccess* file but there is not one there (I have looked for hidden files). I searched the sub directories and did find one *.htaccess* file at *./wp-content/plugins/akismet/.htaccess* which was created or modified in July. Also Akismet seems to be to do with spam so I thought it was unlikely to be anything to do with the error I had been getting when I tried to create or edit posts.

Although my WordPress installation now appears to be working, I would like to know why the `AllowOverride` directive change, which seems to be very much to do with enabling *.htaccess* files, solved the problem but did not result in a *.htaccess* appearing in the root directory. I thought I had read that WordPress requires a *.htaccess* file in the root directory.

I would be very interested in understanding what the situation is in relation to *.htaccess* files and WordPress and the results I obtained by changing the `AllowOverride` directive.

Comment: "I made a directory specific (to the root directory of my WordPress installation)" - Not sure what you mean by that? Simply making an arbitrary subdirectory in the root to which you `AllowOverride All` (which is what that sounds like?) doesn't make much sense?

Comment: As @MrWhite points out, changing the server config won't automatically create a `.htaccess` file. You can add one, though, and [here's what WordPress recommends you put in your `.htaccess` file.](https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/)

Comment: I have just removed the `AllowOverride All` directive from my config and restarted apache. Now I am able to make and edit posts. It must have been something else I did (or that happened) which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know why the `AllowOverride` directive change, which seems to be very much to do with enabling `.htaccess` files, solved the problem

If there are no `.htaccess` files then adding `AllowOverride All` in the server config is not going to do anything. As you suggest, `AllowOverride` essentially enables `.htaccess` files to be processed (if any exist along the file-path). Specifically, it allows directives in `.htaccess` to *override* directives that might have been defined in the server config (in a *directory* context).

> I thought I had read that WordPress requires a `.htaccess` file in the root directory.

You can run WordPress without a `.htaccess` file. However, to use "pretty permalinks" (ie. without `/index.php` being present in the URL) you do need a `.htaccess` file (on Apache or LiteSpeed servers).

Although, having said that, everything you can do in `.htaccess` can be done in the main server config (and much more), so you don't strictly need a `.htaccess` file at all.

Comment: Thanks! It is very useful to know I can put the directive on the main server as Apache recommend that where possible. I thought WordPress might need to write to the *.htaccess* file and / or create it in the first place which I could see might be possible whereas WordPress could not write to the main server config. Clearly I was pretty confused but slightly less so now...